# how to use setCaptureScreenShotOnFailure(true) in selenium

Tags: selenium-rc

I have a test class to which i have added a constructor containing a
method setCaptureScreenShotOnFailure(true)
There is an assert statement which gets failed in this test
But even though there is no screenshot being captured ( i checked the
selenium server directory)
Can anyone explain how to work with this method in
I understand i cannot use this in my setup method and i can only use
in the individual test classes
Is it correct?

Comment: it should be in individual class only

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is only  for individual class. However, if you want more effective use then you can implement testng then create a screenshot class which extends to testlistener. So that you can capture screenshot during pass or faliure of tests. refer [Selenium Testng Screenshot Listener](http://satishjohn.wordpress.com/2012/06/04/selenium-testng-error-screenshot-listene/)